# iOS: Game Center Friend Invitation Request View Controller Changes Status Bar Color When Finishing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, game-center, statusbar

I am making an app that includes Game Center feature "Invite Friends" hence I am making it according to Game Center Programming Guide.

The main problem I am facing is the change of color of the Status Bar after dismissing `GKFriendRequestComposeViewController`.

In my application, I am using a dark interface with light style of Status Bar. When I call `GKFriendRequestComposeViewController`, Status Bar color changes to default (e.g. black).
When I finish my actions with `GKFriendRequestComposeViewController` — cancel or send invitation, View Controller removes, Status Bar color animates its changes to white and then instantly changes back to black.

I can't change this behaviour. Here is my code:

Code for showing `GKFriendRequestComposeViewController`:

```
- (void) inviteFriends
{
   GKFriendRequestComposeViewController *friendRequestViewController = [[GKFriendRequestComposeViewController alloc] init];
   friendRequestViewController.composeViewDelegate = self;
   [friendRequestViewController addRecipientsWithPlayerIDs: nil];

   [self presentViewController:friendRequestViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Just like in the Programming Guide.

Code for removing `GKFriendRequestComposeViewController`:

```
- (void)friendRequestComposeViewControllerDidFinish:(GKFriendRequestComposeViewController *)viewController
{
   [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
       NSLog(@"this code is never execute");
   }];

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Here are some problems I am facing. First: If I use `self` instead of `self.presentingViewController` I receive this error:

```
Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController: 0x16d45310> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

So, I use self.presentedViewController. But completion block is never called. Why?

My code doesn't change Status Bar style here, but I use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

in other app parts and it works fine.

By the way, `myApp-Info.plist` contains this settings:

- Status bar is initially hidden — NO
- Status bar style — UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
- View controller-based status bar appearance — NO

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: sorry I encountered the same issue, how do u solve it

Comment: @passol right now I put aside this trouble, later I decide to manually control status bar at each screen due to colour changing in my app.

Comment: @passol hello, I returned to my trouble, if you solved it please write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this to keep statusBar white on iOS7:

```
- (void)friendRequestComposeViewControllerDidFinish:(GKFriendRequestComposeViewController *)viewController
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

Make sure that `View controller-based status bar appearance` in your plist is set to NO.

This - `Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController: 0x14d44a60> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!` means you are presenting a viewController while another presented viewController is animating out (dismissing). to solve it for example:

This makes a problem:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thats the solution:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(delayedPresent:) withObject:nextViewController afterDelay:0.6];

- (void)delayedPresent:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hello again, I'm sorry but I'll unmark your answer and edit my question due to I returned to this problem in my project and unfortunately I can't solve it with this answer :(